Sigma algebra generated by function induced by a generated sigma algebra
I just started "Measure theory" by Fremlin, as the author points out, there is this issue with doing first Lebesgue integrable functions and then talk about measure (which is the path that I took when I was an undergrad) or do the "inverse" path of first talking about sigma algebras and then do Lebesgue measure and integral (which is the path that he takes).
I was going through the exercises for sigma algebras that I consider to be interesting or non-trivial (at least for me at the moment) but I got stuck on one.
I managed to prove the most basic properties, given two sets $X$ and $Y$, and a map $f\colon X\longrightarrow Y$:

If $\Sigma$ is a sigma algebra of $X$, then $\{F\colon F\subseteq Y, f^{-1}[F]\in \Sigma \}$ is a sigma algebra of $Y$.
If $T$ is a sigma algebra of $Y$, then $\{f^{-1}[F]\colon F\in T\}$ is a sigma algebra of $X$.

But then I got stuck on the following:

Let $\mathcal{A}\subseteq\mathcal{P}(Y)$, then $T=\{f^{-1}[E]\colon E\in \Sigma_{\mathcal{A}}\}$ is the sigma algebra of $X$ generated by $\mathcal{B}=\{f^{-1}[A]\colon A\in\mathcal{A}\}$, meaning $T=\Sigma_{\mathcal{B}}$. $\quad$($\Sigma_{\mathcal{A}}$ denotes the sigma algebra generated by the family of subsets $\mathcal{A}$)

By the second point $T$ is a sigma algebra of $X$. It is very easy to see that $\mathcal{B}\subseteq T$, but this is as far as I have reached.
I tried to prove the other inclusion, by trying to show that every sigma algebra of $X$ that contains $\mathcal{B}$ has to include $T$, that would prove that $T$ is contained in the intersection of all such sigma algebras and completes the proof.
I feel mathematically blind, if that makes any sense.

This is how I found the duplicate (page 3).

@MartinBrandenburg that searcher is only for this site? Should I delete the post?
